# What are these API's?

Tags: android

i'm new to android and i would like to know about these api's..

wen i was browsing the developers guide i found out some thing like Api 1,Api 2,Api 7......etc

what are these Api's and the purpose of their presence.....

Comment: I answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057396/what-does-api-level-mean/9057487#9057487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each API # corresponds to different Adnroid/Android SDK version:

- Api 3 - Android 1.5
- Api 4 - Android 1.6
- etc

Read more about API levels at [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/guide/appendix/api-levels.html).