# What does API level mean?

Tags: android, api

I am wondering what exactly *API level* means. I couldn't seem to find an answer by searching on Google.

Could anyone please explain what the term *API level* means?

Comment: What about this: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html.

Comment: API- Application Programming Interface .The integer number of API is communicated with specific libraries and object to class of support android devices.

Comment: Below link also gives a clear picture of what exactly API level means with device(number of device currently support) to API level support. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/

Answer (score 127, accepted):

[This](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html) actually sums it up pretty nicely.

API Levels generally mean that as a programmer, you can communicate with the devices' built in functions and functionality. As the API level increases, functionality adds up (although some of it can get deprecated).

Choosing an API level for an application development should take at least two thing into account:

1. [Current distribution](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) - How many devices can actually support my application, if it was developed for API level 9, it cannot run on API level 8 and below, then "only" around 60% of devices can run it (true to the date this post was made).
2. Choosing a lower API level may support more devices but gain less functionality for your app. you may also work harder to achieve features you could've easily gained if you chose higher API level.

Android API levels can be divided to five main groups (not scientific, but what the heck):

1. Android 1.5 - 2.3 (Cupcake to Gingerbread) - (API levels 3-10) - Android made specifically for smartphones.
2. Android 3.0 - 3.2 (Honeycomb) (API levels 11-13) - Android made for tablets.
3. Android 4.0 - 4.4 (KitKat) - (API levels 14-19) - A big merge with tons of additional functionality, totally revamped Android version, for both phone and tablets.
4. Android 5.0 - 5.1 (Lollipop) - (API levels 21-22) - Material Design introduced.
5. Android 6.0 - 6.… (Marshmallow) - (API levels 23-…) - Runtime Permissions,Apache HTTP Client Removed

Comment: i'm developing on android 4.0.3 version 15  sdk/api and it works on my 2.3.6 api phone. is it good practice to develop on a higher api then your minimum target. it works, but i'm wondering if I should develop on the same sdk/api as my minimum target api. I've never gotton an answer on this with stack overflow or google support. see this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414179/any-risks-in-using-a-higher-sdk-to-develop-than-the-minsdkversion-target-in-mani.

Answer (score 8):

API level is basically the Android version. Instead of using the Android version name (eg 2.0, 2.3, 3.0, etc) an integer number is used. This number is increased with each version. Android 1.6 is API Level 4, Android 2.0 is API Level 5, Android 2.0.1 is API Level 6, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

An API is ready-made source code library.

In Java for example APIs are a set of related classes and interfaces that come in packages. This picture illustrates the libraries included in the Java Standard Edition API. Packages are denoted by their color.

[image: This pictures illustrates the libraries included in the Java Standard Edition API]

Answer (score 0):

- The API is the android platform that make up the core language that
  you will use when developing, and as you get the API version higher
  the SDK tools should also be updated (which are the tools for
  developing and debugging).
- You should also take into account the market and how many devices
  will support my selected API and choose the lowest API target
  possible for your app to adapt more devices.