# Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I have this line in my code:

```
linearLayout.setBackground(drawable);
```

`setBackground()` shows the following error:

> Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14)

What does this mean?

Can I raise my API level?

What does a higher/lower API level mean?

Does it limit the amount of devices my app can be used on if the API level is higher?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057396/what-does-api-level-mean

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What does this mean?

It means that the `setBackground(Drawable)` method was added in API Level 16, and older devices do not have it. However, your app's `minSdkVersion` is 14. So, unless you take steps to avoid this line on API Level 14 and 15 devices, your app will crash on those devices.

> Can I raise my API level?

You could set your `minSdkVersion` to 16.

> Does it limit the amount of devices my app can be used on if the API level is higher?

Yes. If you say that your `minSdkVersion` is 16, then devices running a version of Android older than that cannot run your app.

At the time of this writing, [about 90% of Android devices accessing the Play Store are on API Level 16 or higher](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) (i.e., are running Android 4.1 or higher).

You can read more about the concept of API levels in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html#Versions). Note that this documentation is a bit old, in that it focuses on the `minSdkVersion` being defined in the manifest. In Android Studio projects, `minSdkVersion` is usually defined in your `app` module's `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 7):

> Can I raise my API level?

You can set API to 16 it will limit device below 16 but it will perfectly work on devices API 16 and higher

> Or else You can use API check and set

```
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ready) );
} else {
    layout.setBackground( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ready));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a validation method that will be supported only in API LEVEL >= 16 (note the use of [**ContextCompat**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html) class:

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
            linearLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, drawableid));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
layout.setBackgroudResource(R.drawable.ready);
```

Comment: @fool-dev : It's an _answer_, not a Q.