# Call requires API level 21 (current min is 14): android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech#speak

Tags: android, speech

I want to implement Text to Speech in my Android Application

But this code gives error:
**Call requires API level 21 (current min is 14): android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech#speak**

```
private fun speakOut(text: String){
   tts!!.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,"")
}
```

Comment: `Call requires API level 21 (current min is 14)` that's your solution right there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call requires API level 16 (current min is 14)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210559/call-requires-api-level-16-current-min-is-14)

Answer (score 0):

As it's said in the error, you should set `minSdkVersion` to 21 in `build.gradle`